# Trying to check a list with another list

Tags: python, list

I am having problems with one part of my program which checks the clues which the user has inputted with the correct and solved version which in an external file solved.txt.

The code which I have runs with no errors however it keeps on saying I have got 0 pairings correct. This is wrong as I have entered a correct pairing into the list of clues to check yet it is still doing the same thing.

The code which I have so far is as shows.

```
def check_clues():
    count = 0
    with open('solved.txt') as r:
         solved = r.readlines()
    with open('clues.txt') as r: 
         pairings = r.readlines()

    for user in pairings:
        if user in solved:
            count += 1

    print('You got:', count, 'correct!')
```

Solved.txt file...

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

Clues.txt

```
A#
M*
N%
```

Coded words which have to be solved...

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

Comment: have you checked whats in `pairings` and `solved` respectively?

Comment: i.e. `print pairings` or `print solved` after reading them in and `print user` inside your loop.

Comment: koxt - what should I check for?

Comment: thomas - That is what I am getting confused about...

Comment: `count =+ 1` in your code. Also check indentation of `for user in pairings:`

Comment: koxt - OK, what should it be?

Comment: probably `count += 1`

Comment: So keep it as it is???

Comment: you should change the solution

Answer (score 0):

You had =+ instead of += and the indentation was a bit screwy, so I'm not sure how it ran without errors, but I think this should work. Also check what format the files are in. If they're comma separated then readlines would result in something like this `[[clue1, clue2, clue3], [clue4, clue5, clue6].... etc]` instead of `[clue1,clue2, clue3, clue4, ...etc]`.

I think this should work:

```
def check_clues():
    count = 0
    # TRIES TO OPEN FILE SOLVED.TXT
    try:
        with open('solved.txt') as r:
    # READS THROUGH ALL THE LINES IN SOLVED.TXT
             solved = r.readlines()
    # WILL DISPLAY AN ERROR MESSAGE IF SOLVED.TXT IS NOT FOUND
    except:
        print("Error finding file")
    # WILL TRY AND OPEN THE FILE 'clues.txt'
    try:
        with open('clues.txt') as r: 
             clues = r.readlines()
    except:
        print("Error finding ")


    # GOES THROUGH BOTH THE USERS CLUES AND SOLVED.TXT TO SEE HOW MANY CLUES ARE THE SAME
    for clue in clues:
        if clue in solved:
            count += 1
    # Prints the amount of clues the user got right out of 10
    print('You got:', count, 'correct!')
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that out ! However it is still doing the same thing as before...

Comment: Edit the question to include what the files look like that you're reading in.

Comment: There, I have added the list of coded words which the user has to solve... Now you should see that they match...

Comment: You're just checking if strings from one file match the strings in another file, you're not doing any kind of encoding or logic on the strings themselves. A matching file would include a matching string like "ALMANAC" not "A#"

Comment: OK, so what do I need to change
?

Comment: It seems like you're not structuring the whole program correctly. Can you clarify what exactly the whole objective is? The information you have provided doesn't explain why you would think that "A#" is in the solved list or how it would relate to any of the coded words list.

Comment: Ok the objective of the program is so that the user has to guess what letters match up with the symbols using logic... They then add the pairing which they think is correct to the list of clues. The user then has the option to check if these pairings which they have with the solved and correct version...

Comment: What you are describing requires some logic to match these. I would seriously reconsider the whole organization of this code and go back through the requirements for what you need done as this code doesn't seem close to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: All I want to to is check that the clues the user has entered are correct or wrong by checking it with the solved version.